# react native 0.64.2 npm audit 7 moderate warnings

Tags: react-native

I have my application created in react native 0.64.2 for some time, I have noticed several error messages when auditing my project (npm audit), I decided to create a new blank project and perform the audit of the packages (npm audit) and it turns out that gives the same problem, I leave the result of the audit

```
% npm audit
# npm audit report

xmldom  *
Severity: moderate
Misinterpretation of malicious XML input - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1769
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-native@0.62.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/xmldom
plist  >=0.3.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of xmldom
node_modules/plist
 @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios  *
 Depends on vulnerable versions of plist
 Depends on vulnerable versions of xcode
 node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios
   react-native  <=0.0.0-ffdfbbec0 || >=0.62.1
   Depends on vulnerable versions of @react-native-community/cli
   Depends on vulnerable versions of @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios
   node_modules/react-native
     @react-native-community/cli  >=5.0.0-alpha.0
     Depends on vulnerable versions of react-native
     node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
 simple-plist  *
 Depends on vulnerable versions of plist
 node_modules/simple-plist
   xcode  >=0.8.3
   Depends on vulnerable versions of simple-plist
   node_modules/xcode

7 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force
```

I don't want to use the command (npm audit fix --force) because I am working with React Native 0.64.2 and that command will replace the project with React Native 0.62.0, I am programming for Android and IOS, any other solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you should NOT run npm audit fix --force. Package makes sure that your dependency structure is consistent between installs. If you force audit fix, you will loose this protection and your code might easily misbehave in ways that are not always immediately apparent.

Please read below:

https://www.voitanos.io/blog/don-t-be-alarmed-by-vulnerabilities-after-running-npm-install/

"I’ve seen more and more questions since the folks at NPM added an automatic scan for vulnerabilities after every NPM install....

Notice it says that these packages (mime & parsejson) are both referenced by one of the core Microsoft packages used by the SharePoint Framework: @microsoft/sp-build-web & @microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench...

These are dependencies someone else has added to their package. You can’t just change the dependencies someone else has taken an expect nothing adverse to happen. Maybe things will work just fine, but does changing dependencies upstream sound like a trivial change? It shouldn’t… because it isn’t."

While I too feel antsy when I see this, I stop, think, and remember best to not do too much. If everything is under source control, you could try https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates. But that is the furtherest I would go.